# Dividing a list of matrices by a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, tidyverse

I have a list of matrices that I like to divide the values in each matrix by a different value.

```
l1 <- list(1,2,3,4,5,6)
l2 <- list(7,8,9,10,11,12)

mat <- Map(
    function(x, y) outer(unlist(x), unlist(y), `+`) / 2,
    split(l1, ceiling(seq_along(l1) / 3)),
    split(l2, ceiling(seq_along(l2) / 3))
)
```

For example the output below shows one of the elements in the `mat` list:

```
$`1`
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  4.0  4.5  5.0
[2,]  4.5  5.0  5.5
[3,]  5.0  5.5  6.0
```

I would like to divide the values in the matrix by another matrix with different values
Maybe a matrix that looks like this (I wasn't sure how to create a matrix in r)

```
2 1 2
3 2 3
1 2 3
```

My desired output would then look like this:

```
     [,1]    [,2]   [,3]
[1,]  4.0/2  4.5/1  5.0/2
[2,]  4.5/3  5.0/2  5.5/3
[3,]  5.0/1  5.5/2  6.0/3
```

How could I do create this output? How do I create a matrix with my desired values in `R`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your matrices are the same dimensions you can divide them with the `/` operator.

```
# create matrix to divide by
mat_div <- matrix(c(2,3,1,1,2,2,2,3,3), nrow = 3)

# divide list of matricies
lapply(mat, `/`, mat_div)

#------
$`1`
     [,1] [,2]     [,3]
[1,]  2.0 4.50 2.500000
[2,]  1.5 2.50 1.833333
[3,]  5.0 2.75 2.000000

$`2`
     [,1] [,2]     [,3]
[1,]  3.5 7.50 4.000000
[2,]  2.5 4.00 2.833333
[3,]  8.0 4.25 3.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Map`

```
mat <- Map(`/`, mat, list(mat2))
```

-otuput

```
mat
$`1`
     [,1] [,2]     [,3]
[1,]  2.0 4.50 2.500000
[2,]  1.5 2.50 1.833333
[3,]  5.0 2.75 2.000000

$`2`
     [,1] [,2]     [,3]
[1,]  3.5 7.50 4.000000
[2,]  2.5 4.00 2.833333
[3,]  8.0 4.25 3.000000
```

#### data

```
mat2 <- cbind(c(2, 3, 1), c(1, 2, 2), c(2, 3, 3))
```